# Assigning column to larger DataFrame in specific positions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two lists.

```
A = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
B = [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to create C:

```
C = [NaN, 2, NaN, NaN, 3, 4, NaN, 5]
```

Basically, where in `A` there is a `1` I want to have a value of `B`, where there is a `0`, a `NaN`.
In reality, `A` contains around 10k elements, `B` around 40k and I have many of them. I am working with a pandas.DataFrame (each "array" is a column of two different dataframes, I have to "fit" `B` in `A` by transforming it into `C`).
I have done it with a for loop, but I am wondering how to do it in a better way. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with the user guide, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html, practicing the examples.

Comment: `A contains around 10k elements, B around 40k` - in your example `A` has more items than `B`. Is the one/zero *array* always bigger or always smaller than the *other* array?

Comment: Will the number of ones in the zero/one *array* always equal the length of the *other* array?

Comment: `A` always bigger than `B`, and the answer to the second question is _yes_.

Comment: Assuming A and B are Numpy ndarrays: `C = np.full(A.shape,np.nan); C[A==1] = B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` and check with `if` condition if it is `0` or not. If it is `0` then provide `None`, else pop B from left side.

```py
[None if i==0 else B.pop(0) for i in A]
```

output

```
[None, 2, None, None, 3, 4, None, 5]
```

Comment: It works like this:  `B = list(B_df['x'])
A_df['x'] = [np.NaN if i==0 else B.pop(0) for i in A_df['ones_and_zeros']]`  but not like this: `A_df['x'] = [np.NaN if i==0 else list(B_df['x']).pop(0) for i in A_df['ones_and_zeros']]`  
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't necessarily want to keep the Int type, you can do that with Numpy:

```
A = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=np.float)
B = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])

A[A == 1] = B
A[A == 0] = np.nan
```

Because the **NaN** object is valid only for an array of float type.
**Warning !** : works only if the number of 1 is equal to the number of elements in array B